# Reading multiple numbers from a file into a struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I have a small bit of code that should read values from a file with the following format:

```
0 0 0
0 0 2
0 2 0
0 2 2
2 0 0
2 0 2
2 2 0
2 2 2
```

into parts of a struct.
I wrote a small program to confirm this was working, but when I print the result I get 0s for every term. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be much appreciated. The test code is:

```
#include <stdio.H>
#include <stdlib.H>

            struct particle
            {
                double x[3];
            };

#define N 8 //number of particles

            struct particle particles[N];

            void starting_positions()
            {
                int p;
                FILE * startingpositions;//any .txt file
                startingpositions = fopen("startingpositions.txt", "r");
                for(p=0;p<N;p++)
                {
                    fscanf(startingpositions,"%lf %lf %lf\n", &particles[p].x[0],&particles[p].x[1],&particles[p].x[2]);
                }
                return;
            }

            int main()
            {
                int p;
                for(p=0;p<N;p++)
                {
                    printf("%lf %lf %lf\n", particles[p].x[0],particles[p].x[1],particles[p].x[2]);
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Why `x` is `double` array? why not `int`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh X can take on noninteger values in the full program.

Comment: @user3121023 very careless of me, thank you!

Comment: Some additional notes: Close the file after reading, check for errors (fscanf, too!), use all lowercase names for standard headers. Next get rid of that global state: pass a pointer to (the first element of) an array of `struct particle` as well as the size of that array to your function.

Comment: @DanielJour thank you for the tips! could you explain that second sentence further please?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is, you never called `starting_positions()` in your `main()`. So, the file is never opened, never read and the elements in the `particles` array are never assigned any value.

So, the `particles` array elements, (`particles` being a *global*) are implicitly initialized to `0` and that's the value it prints.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much, that was very careless of me. Have a good day!